# Can't we make a better variable-length character encoding with just using the 1 bit extra in the 7 bit ASCII?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

What if we used the extra bit as a flag? If the flag is set (1), it indicates that the character continues into the next byte. If not (0), it’s the end of the character.

Where UTF-8 uses

| Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0xxxxxxx |  |  |  |
| 110xxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  |  |
| 1110xxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  |
| 11110xxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |

This uses

| Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0xxxxxxx |  |  |  |
| 1xxxxxxx | 0xxxxxxx |  |  |
| 1xxxxxxx | 1xxxxxxx | 0xxxxxxx |  |
| 1xxxxxxx | 1xxxxxxx | 1xxxxxxx | 0xxxxxxx |

Is it speed because you know the size from the first byte in UTF-8? Is this a trade for size vs speed?

I tried looking for answers by looking into the early history of Unicode. I looked into the original [Unicode 88](https://unicode.org/history/unicode88.pdf) paper and I couldn't find a definitive answer

Comment: UTF-8 has several benefits that your proposal does not: 1) UTF-8 bytes with the high bit set to 0 are always ASCII, but yours may or may not be; 2) looking at just the 1st byte in a UTF-8 sequence, you know immediately how many bytes are in the sequence; 3) looking at any UTF-8 byte, you know immediately whether you are on the 1st byte or on a continuation byte; 4) Starting at any byte in a UTF-8 sequence, you can seek backwards to find the 1st byte of the sequence.  Your proposal requires analyzing surrounding bytes to determine these kind of things, which is more work and processing time.